# Composer update "could not completely remove doctrine/dbal", Laravel 4 broken

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, laravel, composer-php

I just did a Composer update on my Laravel 4 project, after which it completely broke down. It all started with Composer giving me the error "Could not completely remove doctrine/dbal", after which I tried the update again.

At that point the Artisan command `php artisan clear-compiled`, set to run before a Composer update, failed, saying the `redirectIfTrailingSlash()` method (called in bootstrap/start.php) does not exist.

So now my app is giving me the white screen of death, and Composer update/install can't fix it. I've tried removing the lock file and all packages in vendor. No dice.

More info:

- I have no compiled.php file in the bootstrap folder. Artisan probably removed this before the first update that made everything fail.
- My composer.json works, I have updated without trouble many times before.
- I can run Composer if I use --no-scripts or comment out the `redirectIfTrailingSlash()` method call.
- When I run composer update successfully, I get a lot of suggested packages to install, doctrine/dbal being among those. A successful composer update doesn't solve my problem, however.
- The initial composer update was run from my development VM. I have no idea why it would have trouble removing packages, though.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you try upgrading Laravel as there is no need for `redirectIfTrailingSlash()`. If so read the upgrade process here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/upgrade.md If not then the Laravel package is not installing fully/at all.

Comment: Following the upgrade instructions, as FruityP suggested, worked fantastically. Thanks!

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try upgrading Laravel as there is no need for `redirectIfTrailingSlash()`. If so read the upgrade process here github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/upgrade.md

If not then the Laravel package is not installing fully/at all.

*Turns out the comment was the solution.*

Answer (score 0):

These `commands` should help:

`composer remove doctrine/dbal` will solve the problem.

`composer remove packagename` removes package.